# How is this still a thing? (Hat for accepted answer with no votes)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

There was a hat last year awarded to answers that were accepted but did not receive any votes for 12 hours (*Naruto*). This year it has been repeated as a secret hat

> "mild mannered"

The only legitimate situation that comes to my mind for OP to not upvote the accepted answer is when OP is a new user and doesn't have the upvote privilege yet (less than 15 rep). That is unfortunate, as it makes answering questions by newcomers relatively unrewarding.

What is the motivation behind such hat?

Comment: As a side note, I would argue that if not receiving a few extra points every once in a while makes answering questions unrewarding, even relatively, you probably won't be answering questions for long, anyways, since you've got the wrong motivation. Also there's plenty of others who would answer instead, so it's not a problem for you to not answer. As for the hat, it doesn't seem like it *increases* this behavior (I can't imagine how it could) so while it's silly, is it really a *problem*? The hat doesn't encourage anything, really, it just sort of highlights a thing that ... happens.

Comment: @Martin This year, it is "Mild Mannered".

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a thing?

Comment: Only a few hats are repeated each year, that makes this one a bit special. For most of them the motivation is quite clear. I'm genuinely curious what is it for this one.

Comment: While an upvote by the OP is nice, I think the accept is making up for it and more. I got two accepted answers, both without any upvotes for at least 12 hours on the same (small) site and I did not mind.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably for users like me (on Stack Overflow), whose answers are not so appriciated (aka upvoted) or on active sites where questions are constantly posted and people just want to move on and try to get some quick rep on some unaccepted question. The motivation for this hat is probably similar to the badge, [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) and [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious).

Can't the users whose answers are neglected and passed by get some reward for their hard work to fix the OP's problem? For extra effect:

[image]